# Android List adapter with a button

Tags: android

I need to implement a list with a custom list adapter view that contains a button. 
Once I add the button the onClick is not triggered.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Two questions 1. Is your custom adapter layouts correctly? 2. Where do you write your onClickListener for the button?

Comment: Show some code and I'll try to show you an answer! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set the button's android:focusable="false"